# Neo4j Merge doesn't use unique constraint index

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j Version 2.2.4

I use LOAD CSV to import a huge collection of nodes and relationships. I use MERGE to get or create the nodes. For performance I also created a unique index for the node property.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (e:RESSOURCE) assert e.url is unique;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///Users/x/data.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
MERGE (subject:RESSOURCE {url: trim(line[0])})
MERGE (object:RESSOURCE {url: trim(line[1])})
CREATE (subject)-[:EQUIVALENCE]->(object);
```

The problem is that the import of about 1Mio. edges performs very bad. I profiled the import and also single MERGE queries and I couldn't see any usage of the unique index. In contrast a MATCH query makes use of the index. What can I do to use MERGE with the index?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Peter is correct, for some more explanation:

You run into the EAGER problem, see: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/ you should see it in your EXPLAIN output (remove the periodic commit and use explain)

```
+--------------+----------------------------------+-----------------------+
| Operator     | Identifiers                      | Other                 |
+--------------+----------------------------------+-----------------------+
| +EmptyResult |                                  |                       |
| |            +----------------------------------+-----------------------+
| +UpdateGraph | anon[179], line, object, subject | CreateRelationship    |
| |            +----------------------------------+-----------------------+
| +UpdateGraph | line, object, subject            | MergeNode; :RESSOURCE |
| |            +----------------------------------+-----------------------+
| +Eager       | line, subject                    |                       |
| |            +----------------------------------+-----------------------+
| +UpdateGraph | line, subject                    | MergeNode; :RESSOURCE |
| |            +----------------------------------+-----------------------+
| +LoadCSV     | line                             |                       |
+--------------+----------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Eager will pull in your whole CSV file to ensure isolation and effectively disable your periodic commit.

If you do two passes, you could also try:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (e:RESSOURCE) assert e.url is unique;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///Users/x/data.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
FOREACH (url in line[0..1] |
   MERGE (subject:RESSOURCE {url: trim(url)})
);

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///Users/x/data.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
MATCH (subject:RESSOURCE {url: trim(line[0])})
MATCH (object:RESSOURCE {url: trim(line[1])})
CREATE (subject)-[:EQUIVALENCE]->(object);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what we do in our import processes - we first bring all nodes in with one or more CSV's (100000 nodes in each) and then bring in relationships using the above MATCH MATCH MERGE command.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
MATCH (subject:RESSOURCE {url: trim(line[0])}), (object:RESSOURCE {url: trim(line[1])}) 
MERGE (subject)-[:EQUIVALENCE]->(object)
```

**Edit:**
I see you also want to merge the nodes - I would suggest doing a MERGE for each node:

```
MERGE (subject:RESSOURCE {url: trim(line[0])})
```

I also recommend doing the trim when you build the csv file so you limit the number of times neo4j is doing it and simplify this cypher.

**Edit 2** (thanks to comment by Kai who corrected my above MERGE statement):

If you want to do a more complex MERGE with more properties you could do this:

```
MERGE (subject:RESSOURCE {url: trim(line[0])})
  ON CREATE SET source=trim(line[1])
  ON MERGE SET source=trim(line[1])
```

Comment: is there a difference between 

    MERGE (subject:RESSOURCE {url: trim(line[0])})
and 
    MERGE (subject:RESSOURCE {url: trim(line[0])})
        ON CREATE SET subject.url=trim(line[0])

I think the merge already creates the node in the case that it doesn't exist

Comment: Yes, you're right, my mistake. The ON CREATE SET (and related ON MATCH SET) clauses are only needed if you want to set other properties.